# How can a charset tag line of code make my full page reload twice?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have this code:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo $stigConfig['charset']; ?>" />
```

How can this line of code make my full page reload twice?

I've been looking through all over my site. Finally after 2 days, I narrowed the cause down to deleting this line. My site no longer runs its header scripts twice.

Don't I need a charset meta tag?

I have an increment script for increasing users permissing and decearing. I just couldn't figure out why it would skip a `+1`. I was wondering how can a `0+1` give a `2`.
With that charset tag out of the picture it became ok.

Comment: How does this like render in the browser, if you `view source`?

Comment: the source is fine. i put a write log function to my query class so i generate a log file. all my querys run twice if i leave this charset meta. i take it out they run once. but it would seem its  like a page refresh in the source i only see the page once.

Comment: @StiGMaT ; the source is fine? umm... obviously, it's not, if removing it stopped the unintended behavior.

Comment: what do you mean? I've seen many sites use this meta charset line. and ive used it before. This is the first time that this line makes the site refresh and reload. The source comes out as expected.. just the over all scripts are ran twice. Whats wierd if the sites reloads once whys isnt it looping? I mean if it runs a script that run it again why isnt it looping? it happens so fast i dont see the refresh. its only threw the logs that i see the script ran my querys 2 times... for that 1 page request

Comment: The page is being loaded twice because the headers and the HTML don't agree on what charset the page should be, so the browser has to reparse the page once it learns what the real charset is.

Comment: ya that makes sense alot. i added a header('Content-Type: text/html; charset='.$stigConfig['charset']); in my first script and it solved the issue :)

Comment: A charset mismatch should not generally cause a reload. What browser are you using? Is it IE8? Is it up-to-date? Could you be looking at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/01/ie8-lookahead-downloader-fixed.aspx) unpleasant bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a charset tag in the HTML if either the web server or the PHP script send the proper header in the first place.

Comment: ill use header('Content-Type: text/html; charset='.$stigConfig['charset']); i guess then